# Azure DevOps pipeline with Flutter Drive test framwork and AppCenter device sets

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, flutterdriver

We have an Azure DevOps build pipeline that setup to create and deploy a Flutter mobile cross-platform app to Microsoft AppCenter. We use the Flutter Driver test framework for UI Automation. We wanted to run the tests with AppCenter's device sets. However, the build pipeline currently only allows us to select one of these test frameworks: Appium, Espresso, Calabash, Xamarin UI Test, XCUITest (and no one for Flutter Driver). Is it possible to setup one for Flutter Driver test? Is there any workaround, customized setup that can make it to work?

Comment: Hi @VinhCao,

As I explained in my answer, Flutter Driver test framework is not currently supported on App Center. You can try to report a feature request for App Center.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the build pipeline currently only allows us to select one of these test frameworks: Appium, Espresso, Calabash, Xamarin UI Test, XCUITest (and no one for Flutter Driver).

This limitation is not from Azure Pipelines, it's from App Center.

The following test frameworks are currently supported on App Center (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/) for more details).

- **Appium**
- **Calabash**
- **Espresso**
- **Xamarin.UITest (iOS, Android)**
- **XCUITest**

**Flutter Driver** test framework is not supported currently.

So, on the [**App Center Test task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/app-center-test?view=azure-devops), only these supported test frameworks are available.

If your projects really need **Flutter Driver** test framework on App Center, I recommend that you can directly share a feature request on the [repository for App Center](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/new/choose) to ask adding the **Flutter Driver** test framework on App Center.